# cannot import name SQLALchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have installed flask-sqlalchemy via pip.But something wrong happened when I run the program,that is, "cannot import name SQLALchemy"At first,I thought the problem was the improper installation.However,I still couldn't solve the problem after several uninstall and installation.Then I change the first line into "from flask_sqlalchemy import sqlalchemy" ,it became "name SQLALchemy is not defined",Still didn't work...What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKhwv.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc1TG.jpg)

Comment: Please add textual context as text in the question and not as images. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your Python interpreter and then use:

```
>>> from flask import Flask
>>> from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

this should work. Your original code has a typo

Comment: sure, feel free to upvote and accept my answer then ;) which was the first

Answer (score 1):

I believe that imports are case sensitive.

Try `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` instead of `SQLALchemy`